# Google App Engine Python/Flask - Serving static folder from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

I have deployed a website using Python and Flask on to Google App Engine successfully, but the performance seems to be pretty slow when first loading the page. I was reading that hosting some of the static files on Cloud Storage would possibly help with this, but I can not seem to get it to work. ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is just for illustration purposes)

Below is the app.yaml file:

```yaml
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script:  main.app

env_variables:
    CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: www.example.com\static

builtins:
- deferred: on
```

I also created a Cloud Storage bucket named [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with a static folder inside of it. I don't know if I need to change the url_for('static') in my jinja2 templates or what I need to do to fix this. I don't care to upload to the Cloud Storage just want to point my websites resources from there.

Any help is appreciated. By the way this is on Standard environment not flex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't fixed on using cloud storage but are happy to just use the built-in static file serving features of Google App Engine, you could write your `app.yaml` file like so…

```
runtime: python39

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Based on example from Google: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/edb0f178896b8d55a2f544b5fe6bbf7ed870a2e9/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-2/app.yaml

(Note, since the original question is years old now, I've updated the version of Python and left out some of the OP's example settings which are not  necessary for this example to work.)